# Excel how to change column numbering by adding a number to the column

Tags: excel

I need to drag cells which equal values of columns which have a distance of for example 4 columns horizontally. Is there any way to add a number for example in column `A` to get column `E`?
Example:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  
1  2  2  3  4  1  5  6  9  1  2
```

I need the values only of columns `A`, `E` and `I` in other cells which are at the right of these cells without leaving empty cells and by dragging horizontally.

Comment: Dragging is something you would do, not code. Are you speaking of VBA code, of formulas. Could you include the expected end result, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am expecting to get only the values 1,4,9 which are the values of the columns A, E, and I. With the function column I can get the column number in order to add the distance of the columns in order to get the next value. For example the column E is column(A)+4. My problem is how to translate back the number into column number so as to have E. My new shells should have the values for example A(3), E(3) and I(3). The inverse function of the column function is to me not known. If you have an idea hot to inverse the column function.

Comment: I have read about index, address etc but I do not get the functionality of these functions. The simplest way I fund is the answer I gave below.

Answer (score 0):

A wax to do this is to change the numbering of the columns from letters to numbers (file->options->formulas->work with formulas-> tick the first field Column Line). 
Then the programming with numbers is easier than using commands to change the column letters in numbers and vice versa. To change the column letters into numbers can also be done with thefunction column. However the inverse function of this is a combination of functions and it is quite difficult to do.